# How use Roslyn Scripting in OSX with F#?

Tags: macos, scripting, f#, .net-4.5, roslyn

I'm getting confusing with the pletora of assemblies that I get from nuget related to Roslyn. I have last version of xamarin with .NET 4.5 profile. I wish to use the scripting part of Roslyn. But don't found how setup the project.

What si the package from nuget I need to download? Is my impression, but the names of the namespaces have changed? Because the tutorial I have found using C# not match what I have get from nuget

Comment: Are you interested in C# scripting or F# scripting?

Comment: I wish F# scripting, but today is not easy to do it (is necesary to call the F# compiler, instead roslyn can be embebed). So, I will do C# for now...

Comment: Why do you think that F# is not easy? Have you looked at the docs? https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html

Comment: Because it need to call fsi.exe

Comment: No, it doesn't. Take a look at the link I posted above.

Comment: @mamcx Do you mean you want to use the Roslyn C# scripting API from F# code (Roslyn only support C# and VB)?

Comment: @ Fyodor Soikin I run the sample code and yes, it not use the .exe! I was mislead by the presence of the string there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last version of Visual Studio for Mac, I can finally create .NET Standard Library and reference the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) NUGET packages.